# How do i interpret IB API reqPositions() response?

Tags: python, api, interactive-brokers

How do i interpret this API response

```
<position account=DU226955, contract=<ib.ext.Contract.Contract object at 0x10be14650>, pos=3000, avgCost=0.903681278811>
<positionEnd>
```

everything is correct but how do i get the contract name out of this?

Comment: Is `ib.ext.Contract.Contract` something you implemented? Look into `__repr__` and `__str__`.

Comment: It's from the ibpy module, am looking into it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the contract symbol (for example) from the message that IbPy returns to your handler, you can do this:

```
def handler(msg):
    print(msg.contract.m_symbol)
```